# Swift Realm: Thread Safe Concurrent Read and Write Index out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am attempting to do a concurrent read and write safely on the Realm database. This is what I am trying to achieve.

I'm pulling images from Flickr, and once `imageData` has been downloaded, the `Photo` object is written into the Realm database. I have also included a `notification` to listen for `insertions`. Once a Photo object has been written to Realm, update that same item's `transport` property. However, my implementation crashes occasionally, ie crashes once every 3-5 times of implementing.

Code as such:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    subscribeToRealmNotifications()
}

fileprivate func subscribeToRealmNotifications() {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let results = realm.objects(Photo.self)

        token = results.observe({ (changes) in
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                self.setupInitialData()
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

            case .update(_, _, let insertions, _):
                if !insertions.isEmpty {
                    self.handleInsertionsWhenNotified(insertions: insertions)
                }

            case .error(let error):
                self.handleError(error as NSError)
            }
        })

    } catch let error {
        NSLog("Error subscribing to Realm Notifications: %@", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

fileprivate func handleInsertionsWhenNotified(insertions: [Int]) {
    let lock = NSLock()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", qos: .userInitiated) //Serial queue

    queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let objects = realm.objects(Photo.self)

            lock.lock()
            for insertion in insertions {
                print(insertion, objects.count, objects[insertion].id ?? "")
                let photo = objects[insertion] //Crash here
                self.update(photo: photo)
            }

            lock.unlock()

        } catch let error {
            NSLog("Error updating photos in Realm Notifications", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func update(photo: Photo) {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let updatedPhoto = createCopy(photo: photo)

        let transport = Transport()
        transport.name = searchText
        updatedPhoto.transport = transport

        try realm.write {
            realm.add(updatedPhoto, update: true)
        }
    } catch let error {
        NSLog("Error updating photo name on realm: %@", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func createCopy(photo: Photo) -> Photo {
    let copiedPhoto = Photo()
    copiedPhoto.id = photo.id
    copiedPhoto.farm = photo.farm
    copiedPhoto.server = photo.server
    copiedPhoto.secret = photo.secret
    copiedPhoto.imageData = photo.imageData
    copiedPhoto.name = photo.name
    return copiedPhoto
}

//On push of a button, call fetchPhotos to download images.
fileprivate func fetchPhotos() {
    FlickrClient.shared.getPhotoListWithText(searchText, completion: { [weak self] (photos, error) in
        self?.handleError(error)

        guard let photos = photos else {return}

        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1", qos: .userInitiated , attributes: .concurrent)

        queue.async { 
            for (index, _) in photos.enumerated() {
                FlickrClient.shared.downloadImageData(photos[index], { (data, error) in
                    self?.handleError(error)

                    if let data = data {
                        let photo = photos[index]
                        photo.imageData = data
                        self?.savePhotoToRealm(photo: photo)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self?.photosArray.append(photo)

                            if let count = self?.photosArray.count {
                                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: count - 1, section: 0)
                                self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}

fileprivate func savePhotoToRealm(photo: Photo) {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let realmPhoto = createCopy(photo: photo)

        try realm.write {
            realm.add(realmPhoto)
            print("Successfully saved photo:", photo.id ?? "")
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Error writing to photo realm: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Note that the above code crashes once every 3-5 times, so I suspect that the read and writes are not done safely. The print log and error logs are as shown when it does crash

```
Successfully saved photo: 45999333945 
4 6 31972639607 
6 7 45999333945 
Successfully saved photo: 45999333605 
Successfully saved photo: 45999333675 
7 8 45999333605 
8 9 45999333675 
Successfully saved photo: 45999333285 
Successfully saved photo: 33038412228 
2019-01-29 14:46:09.901088+0800 GCDTutorial[24139:841805] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 9 is out of bounds (must be less than 9).'
```

Would anybody help to tell where have I gone wrong?

NOTE: I have tried running `queue.sync` at `handleInsertionsWhenNotified`. Doing so eliminates the crash totally, but freezes the UI as it runs on the main thread. This is not ideal in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying the logs a little more carefully, I observed that the object count does not tally whenever the app crashes. In other words, the total object count printed when Realm notifies an insertion is 9 (even though physically inspecting the realm database via the browser showed more than 9), but the insertion index is 9.

This means that when the query is made, the object count probably isn't updated yet (not too sure why). After reading more articles on realm docs and [here](https://academy.realm.io/posts/threading-deep-dive/?_ga=2.105221831.518075449.1548641227-1697836637.1546997338), I implemented `realm.refresh()` before querying the objects. This solves the problem.

```
//Updated code for handleInsertionsWhenNotified
fileprivate func handleInsertionsWhenNotified(insertions: [Int]) {
    let lock = NSLock()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", qos: .userInitiated) //Serial queue

    queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            realm.refresh() // Call refresh here
            let objects = realm.objects(Photo.self)

            lock.lock()
            for insertion in insertions {
                print(insertion, objects.count, objects[insertion].id ?? "")
                let photo = objects[insertion] //Crash here
                self.update(photo: photo)
            }

            lock.unlock()

        } catch let error {
            NSLog("Error updating photos in Realm Notifications", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 0):

The CollectionView insert row calling first called numberOfIteminSection. I hope this code is Work.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: count - 1, section: 0)
self?.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
```

Comment: The crash doesn't happen on the `collectionView.insertItems`. It's inside the `handleInsertionsWhenNotified`.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question.